# Why does clang use this long code sequence to build a 64-bit constant?

Tags: assembly, clang, 64-bit, llvm, riscv

From source:

```
unsigned long div1000(unsigned long a)
{
    return a/1000;
}
```

Optimized code (-O3):

```
    srli    a0, a0, 3           # divide parameter by 8

    lui     a1, 4194            #
    addiw   a1, a1, 1245        #
    slli    a1, a1, 13          #
    addi    a1, a1, 1507        #  8 instruction sequence to assemble a rather large number
    slli    a1, a1, 12          #
    addi    a1, a1, 1343        #
    slli    a1, a1, 12          #
    addi    a1, a1, 1999        #

    mulhu   a0, a0, a1          # multiply by large number and fetch high portion
    srli    a0, a0, 4           # divide by 16
    ret
```

Reference: https://godbolt.org/z/mNNSM5

We can build a 32-bit constant using `lui`/`addi` pair, so why not build 2 x 32-bit constants and put them together.  It would take another register but fewer instructions.

```
lui  a1, ?              # 
addi a1, a1, ?          #
slli a1, a1, 32         #  6 instruction sequence to assemble a 64-bit number
lui  a2, ?              #
addi a2, a2, ?          #
add  a1, a1, a2         #
```

(Note that in the case (as here) that the low order constant, in 32-bits, has the high bit (MSB) set, I presume that `lui` on 64-bit RISC V produces a 32-bit constant that is sign extended into 32-bits.  So, we would have to use the normal trick of creating the high order constant in `a1` off by 1 to offset the negative value in `a2`.)

Comment: Sounds like a missed optimization bug that you should report on https://bugs.llvm.org/.  RISC-V is new enough that it's not surprising that LLVM hasn't implemented code to find every peephole optimization; maybe nobody thought of that, or that's just a generic LLVM pattern without a RISC-V peephole.

Comment: `lui`, `addi`, `slli 16`, `addi`, `slli 16`, `addi` should also work - and do it in 6 instructions using no additional register.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, unlike MIPS, the RISC V `addi` has only a 12 bit immediate (`lui` has 20 bits), so that is sequence is preferable but will only work for some constants.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: that has less ILP, being one dependency chain.  If you have a spare register, better to use more LUI, less ADDI.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the tags correctly.  For some reason I was thinking it's about MIPS-64...